# unpaid monthly salaries (mysql +vb.net)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, select

I have a MySQL table some thing like that

```
NAME  salary amount   month 1   month 2  month 3  month 4
john  300             300       300      0        0
maria 400             400       0        0        0 
tom   380             380       380      380      0
```

I wanna see results in table or list view or whatever like that

```
name    unpaid month    salary amount
john     month 3        300
john     month 4        300
maria    month 2        400
maria    month 3        400
maria    month 4        400
tom      month 4        380
```

I tried code like:

```
sql1="select name,month1 from table where month1=0 "
 sql2="select name,month2 from table where month2=0"
 sql3="select name,month3 from table where month3=0"
sql4="select name,month4 from table where month4=0"
Dim Sql = String.Concat(sql1, ";", sql2 ,";",sql2,";",sql4 )
```

but didn't work , any help pls ?

Comment: What's 'amount' in your results table supposed to be?

Comment: would be the same column in table  'salary amount'

Comment: If you think about it, how will your table cope as the months roll on? Will it keep expanding to the right every month? I think you'll be better off if you restructure your table instead to these columns: ```Month, Name, Salary```, and have Month and Name form a composite key to prevent duplicates.

Comment: it will expanding to 12 months , but I need duplicated results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks a little off in your code that you have now. I do not know if this is the exact code that you have in your program, but when the SQL statements are not properly formatted nothing will happen. I have made some changes to show what may be the issue.

```
sql1="SELECT name, month1, amount FROM table WHERE month1=0"
sql2="SELECT name, month2, amount FROM table WHERE month2=0"
sql3="SELECT name, month3, amount FROM table WHERE month3=0"
sql4="SELECT name, month4, amount FROM table WHERE month4=0"
Dim Sql = String.Concat(sql1, ";", sql2 ,";",sql2,";",sql4 )
```

The issue that I see with your current formatting is that you may want to have two separate tables for the name and the pay. With the separate tables you could then use foreign keys and join the two tables to have each name on every month with the amount they were paid that month. You would also be able to group the users based off of their name using `GROUP BY`

With the restructured table your call would be as simple as the statement below. Since I do not know your table names I have made fake ones for them.

```
Dim Sql = "SELECT NameTable.name, MonthTable.month, MonthTable.amount 
           FROM NameTable INNER JOIN MonthTable
           ON {prmarykey for name} = {foreign key for month}
           GROUP BY NameTable.name"
```

This should give you the result that you are looking for. Let me know if you have any questions or need clarification.

Comment: I think your answer was very helpful the idea it 's crate new table for months and names related with personal data table , I have to renew  the entire data base , thank you dear sir +1

Answer (score 0):

Try the UNION mysql aggregate :

```
sql1="select name,month1 as unpaid_month from table where month1=0 "
sql2="select name,month2 as unpaid_month from table where month2=0"
sql3="select name,month3 as unpaid_month from table where month3=0"
sql4="select name,month4 as unpaid_month from table where month4=0"
Dim Sql = String.Concat(sql1, " UNION ", sql2 ,"UNION ",sql2," UNION ",sql4
```

Comment: unknown column 'name' in field list

Comment: I have just take your example.

Answer (score 0):

How you could use spaces before column names.

I would suggest you to use `UNION`.

But, here's the least version of SQL;

```
sql = "SELECT NAME, month1 as unpaid_month, salary_amount FROM tablename WHERE month1 = 0"
sql = sql & " UNION "
sql = sql & "SELECT NAME, month2 as unpaid_month, salary_amount FROM tablename WHERE month2 = 0"
sql = sql & " UNION "
sql = sql & "SELECT NAME, month3 as unpaid_month, salary_amount FROM tablename WHERE month3 = 0"
sql = sql & " UNION "
sql = sql & "SELECT NAME, month4 as unpaid_month, salary_amount FROM tablename WHERE month4 = 0"
```

But, the query is not good enough. What will happen if someone is paid half of its salary. And why you should get more than one record for a single person? Shouldn't there be any SUM for salary_amount and string concatenation for unpaid_month?

As it wasn't the part of your question, I can't post the advanced SQL here. Please ask for it in comment if you want that.

Please read these functions `SUM()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` with temporary table `AS TABLE`. I think that you should use them for good programming.

Comment: your idea is worked nice , thanks , but I think its better to create another table for months and salary related with names table